# I'm using AWS SDK for SES to send marketing emails. How do I make it so the 'recipient' is a loop that reads a csv?

Tags: python, sdk, amazon-ses

I took the python code example on AWS SES (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-an-email-using-sdk-programmatically.html) to send a marketing email to clients. However, as they have it set up it only accepts one recipient at a time. I am trying to use SES instead of outlook and SMTP etc. to read a csv with a list of emails and cannot figure out how to incorporate it with the SES script.

The exact error is:

ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Destination.ToAddresses[0], value: {}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

That said, I don't think that's all that is wrong here.

Sorry for any vernacular errors in advance I am new to this.

This is what I have and it is not working (probably obviously):

And my account is no longer in sandbox mode.

```
import csv
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
SENDER = "email@email.com"

# Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
# is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
RECIPIENT = {}
with open("testemailpop.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # Skip header row
    for name, email, message in reader:
        print(f"Sending email to {name}")

AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
# The subject line for the email.
SUBJECT = "Hello from Me"
# The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
BODY_TEXT = ("Hello"
             "Sincerely,"
             "Me"
             )
# The HTML body of the email.
BODY_HTML = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>Hello,</p>


  <p>Sincerely,</p>
  <p>Me</br>
  

</body>
</html>
            """

# The character encoding for the email.
CHARSET = "UTF-8"

# Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)

# Try to send the email.
try:
    #Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_HTML,
                },
                'Text': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                },
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': SUBJECT,
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER,
        # If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
        # following line
        #ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET,
    )
# Display an error if something goes wrong.
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was use a script to loop through the csv and log in to the SES SMTP server like any other server.